# How to implement jQuery click event in magento knockout JS function

Tags: magento2, jquery, knockoutjs

how to implement below jQuery code into knockout js, Actually I'm trying to call this function on a button click event using knockout js, but it's not working

**HTML code:**

```
<div>
    <ul class="list-group">
       <li>
        <button id="buttonid">click</button>
        Item 1
       </li>
        <li>
        <button id="buttonid">click</button>
        Item 2
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery COde:**

```
$('#buttonid').on("click",".list-group-item",function(e){
console.log($(this).text());
console.log(e.target.id);
});
```

In this code .list-group-item is the class of ul tag. Here I wanna try to get title text of li items.

please guide me to implement above jQuery function in knockout js!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Template**

- Removed id's since there shouldn't be more than one element on page with the same id
- Wrapped list item text with a span since trying to output the text of the `li` element would also output the button text

**With Magento Init Script**

```
<div>
    <ul class="list-group" data-role="item-announcer">
        <li>
            <button data-action="announce-item">click</button>
            <span data-role="item">Item 1</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button data-action="announce-item">click</button>
            <span data-role="item">Item 2</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-role=item-announcer]": {
            "Magento_Theme/js/item-announcer": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

**With Data Mage Init Attribute**

```
<div>
    <ul class="list-group" data-mage-init='{"Magento_Theme/js/item-announcer": {}}'>
        <li>
            <button data-action="announce-item">click</button>
            <span data-role="item">Item 1</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button data-action="announce-item">click</button>
            <span data-role="item">Item 2</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Component**

In *app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Theme/web/js/item-announcer.js*:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'domReady!'
], function($) {
    return function(config, element) {
        let actionSelector = '[data-action=announce-item]';
        let itemSelector = '[data-role=item]';

        $(element).on('click', actionSelector, function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let item = $(this).siblings(itemSelector);
            console.log(item.text());
        });
    }
});
```

## With Knockout Component

**Template**

```
<?php
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template $block */
$jsId = $block->getJsId();
$items = [
    [
        'name' => 'Item 1'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Item 2'
    ]
];
?>

<div data-bind="scope: 'item-announcer-<?= $jsId; ?>'">
    <ul class="list-group" data-bind="visible: isVisible()" style="display: none;">
        <!-- ko foreach: items -->
        <li>
            <button data-bind="click: $parent.announce">click</button>
            <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        </li>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "item-announcer-<?= $jsId; ?>": {
                        "component": "Magento_Theme/js/item-announcer",
                        "items": <?= json_encode($items); ?>
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Component**

In *app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Theme/web/js/item-announcer.js*:

```
define([
    'uiComponent'
], function(Component) {
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            items: []
        },

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        initObservable: function () {
            this._super()
                .observe('items');
            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Announce Text
         *
         * @param item
         */
        announce: function (item) {
            console.log(item.name);
        },

        /**
         * Get whether component is visible
         *
         * @returns {boolean}
         */
        isVisible: function () {
            return this.items().length > 0;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort Man!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement the jquery click event that you can refer the document as sometime knockout component call after the dom render you can use the below document jquery selector for the click event.

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', '#your_selector', function (event) {
       console.log("element click");
}
```

Also in the html file you can use the data-bind click event as below and add name of your component js function.

```html
<button data-bind="attr: {title: $t('your title')}, click: function_name" id="selector_id" class="button action primary" type="button">
        <span data-bind="i18n: ButtonText"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks brother! I also got some help from your solution.